# Pandas Mask on multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, nan, mask

In my dataframe I want to substitute every value below 1 and higher than 5 with nan.

This code works

```
persDf = persDf.mask(persDf < 1000)
```

and I get every value as an nan but this one does not:

```
persDf = persDf.mask((persDf < 1) and (persDf > 5))
```

and I have no idea why this is so. I have checked the man page and different solutions on apparentely similar problems but could not find a solution. Does anyone have have an idea that could help me on this?

Comment: replace `and` with `|`

Comment: A value cant be both? Its `or`, better yet use `|` and in this cause I would use: `np.where((persDf< 1) | (persDf> 5), np.NaN, persDf) `

Comment: @Erfan: I want to get a dataframe back so I stick to the mask command. Strangely enough using or gives me a Exception has occurred: ValueError but | works as I wish. Thanks. You can create an answer I gonna accept if you wish.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `|` operator, because a value cant be `< 1` AND `> 5`:

```
persDf = persDf.mask((persDf < 1) | (persDf > 5))
```

Another method would be to use `np.where` and call that inside `pd.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.where((df < 1) | (df > 5), np.NaN, df), 
             columns=df.columns)
```